# How to make Kestrel update on the fly with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have this command (default one) in project.json:

```
"commands": {
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
```

},

Now after I do run Kestrel and change my controller there is no automatic update. As far as I remember it did work in beta-8 automatically (when there was IISExpress). Is there a way to make the same now?

P.S. I also did not find any command apart from Ctrl+C that closes the server that you can run in command line. Maybe there is some hidden one that restarts it?

Update:
It seems that we need to run "dnx-watch web", but Visual Studio by default runs "dnx" command. I am not sure how this can be changed (or if it's possible to change "dnx" to "dnx-watch"

Comment: What do you mean by saying "when there was IISExpress"? It still works for **rc1-final**.

Comment: You are right, it still works very well with IISExpress. But when I switch to web (Kestrel), then it's not supported as easily. I thought it was dnx feature rather than IISExpress, seems I am mistaken since it does not work with "web" by default but works with IISExpress

Answer (score 2):

You can use dnx-watch. Here is more info: [Integrating Visual Studio Code with dnx-watch to develop ASP.NET 5 applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingVisualStudioCodeWithDnxwatchToDevelopASPNET5Applications.aspx).

Comment: Is there an easy way to make it work with Visual Studio (not code?), like some command "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --watch dnx" or something. I tried different ones (after installing dnx watch) but it does not help. For some reason as Yves noticed everything works fine with IISExpress, but not Kestrel

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did based on @tugberk's answer.

1. Installed the dnx-watch command:
   `dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher`
2. Added gulp-shell to package.json under 'devDependencies'
3. Added `var shell = require('gulp-shell');` to gulpfile.js
4. Added `gulp.task('watch', shell.task(['dnx-watch web']));` to gulpfile.js
5. If you want `dnx-watch` to run when you open your project, add the 'watch' task as a [Project Open](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) binding within the Task Runner Explorer.

Now if you make a change to your code and hit ctrl+s, dnx-watch will restart your app without you needing to explicitly build the project.