# Make web command restart Kestrel (kill existing instances) in ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I use the web command to run a console Kestrel web service from the default project setup in Visual Studio. When Kestrel is already running, then it fails to start because the port is occupied, so I need to close the running one first. Is it possible to add some parameters or some other way to make it automatically kill running Kestrel? E.g. on IISExpress you can run as much as you like, no need to kill the running IISExpress.

It looks like that for me now:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
```

}

Comment: By using a `gulp` or `grunt` task maybe

Comment: @aguafrommars not quite sure what you mean

Comment: `grunt` has a `grunt-kill` task to kill a process, may be you can use it to kill Kestrel` on each build

Comment: I see, I suppose I can try this trick, but I hope there is a better way :)

Comment: Have you looked at `dnx-watch` command?

Comment: I was not able to do that in Visual Studio, asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612062/how-to-make-kestrel-update-on-the-fly-with-visual-studio. There is a guide for VS code, but not for ordinary visual studio

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by default, all projects are configured to run at port 5000, IISExpress is able to run multiple services at the same time because it registers each in a different port. To do this with Kestrel you need to specify the port in the launch command. You can do this in the project.json file on the commands section, changing the web command to something like this

"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004"

source: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html

Comment: But this will not help since this port will become occupied right away after the first launch?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik yes but that's why you'd need to setup a different port for each site, so they can all run at the same time

Comment: It's not for different sites that I need that, but for the same site. So I change some code and need to rerun the server. I need to kill it first and then start, would be better to restart :)

Comment: Ah ok, so you need is a function like the dnu-watch this works outside visual studio so you'd need to reattach, there seems to not be a way to have visual studio do this, but as some people said on the comments, a grunt or gulp task can do the trick.Now you can also enable edit-and-continue in VS when you hit a break point

Comment: Yes, I hope in the RC2 or in release the add something by default :)